# Long data is not posting using ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I am using ASIFormDataRequest to send data to server. I am posting a string to server. This string contains encoded image in base64 format. When string length is approx 70,000 character or 70 kb approx, request works fine but when length goes to 130,000 characters or approx. 125 kb, string is not posted to server.

Initially, I supposed this is an server issue so I increased the length in config file too high. But I designed an aspx page where I put a textfield and submit button. I entered same string (approx. 130,000 characters) and submit it and it saved in database successfully. Which suggests that there is no issue on server side and problem occurs in mobile end.

I am not able to find any solution. Please help me to out of this problem. I am also posting the source code:

```
NSString *string = @"fdfd..."; // very long string. Approx. 130,000 characters long

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:string forKey:@"encryptedJson"];

[request setDelegate:self];

[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(sendFormRequestDone:)];

[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(sendFormRequestWentWrong:)];

[request startSynchronous];
```

Comment: What of the two specified selectors is called?

Comment: sendFormRequestDone is called

Answer (score 0):

Please do this

```
  ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request retain];
```